# image classification using image generator

Tags: keras, image-processing, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am using image data generator from keras for image classification.

```
model = Sequential()


model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation="relu",padding='same', input_shape=(320,175,3)))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
# model.add(Dropout(0.25))

#conv2
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation="relu",padding='same'))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
# model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    
model.add(Flatten())
 
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
# model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)

model.compile(optimizer='adam' , loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID, epochs=5)
```

when I use batch size=32 training acc in the first epoch reaches 99% but when I use batch size=512 training acc in the first epoch=70%. why this happens?